# Using data from Meteor Template subscription

Tags: templates, meteor, subscription

I am trying to use Template subscriptions

http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/Blaze-TemplateInstance-subscribe

MeteorPad: http://meteorpad.com/pad/f6EXKWtB9oG8jazx7/Leaderboard

Template.subscriptionsReady works (the not ready disappears after a short while)
but I cannot access the data in the template

```
{{#each players}}
      One line for each player
{{/each}}
```

I had misunderstood Template subscriptions - I thought they would give a data context as well.

Comment: If you subscribe in a controller waitOn function, and then set players to the data that could solve this also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to return this data in helper like:

/client/app.js

```
Template.leaderboard.helpers({
  players: function () {
    return Players.find({});
  }
});
```

http://meteorpad.com/pad/nJ2XoMvFpotSqB2CC/Copy%20of%20Leaderboard

Comment: I think I have misunderstood template subscriptions - I thought they could set the data context (like Iron Router) with out helpers, but I guess helpers are still needed. The (only) clever part is that I don't have to unsubscribe (but that is still cool)

Comment: yeah, subscriptions gives you only an access to your data